# Anything faster than ImageMagick?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, imagemagick, python-imaging-library, perlmagick

Is there anything faster to ImageMagick ? I'm processing images with different kind of filters so to create effects like old photo, oil paint etc.

Answer (score 13):

Check GraphicsMagick. It is based on IM, but faster and less complicated.

Performance copmarison (GraphicsMagick vs ImageMagick):

http://www.graphicsmagick.org/benchmarks.html

Comment: Wow, very significant for many things. thanks for informing me!